# I can't format disk with macOS Journaled in Monterey

Tags: macos

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559).

Opened the Disk Utility app to format an external hard drive and I see these options:

[image]

There is no option **macOS Journaled**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Big Sur, Time Machine volumes *must* be formatted APFS.
HFS+ is no longer supported. Remove that disk as a Time Machine destination if you need more options while erasing it using Disk Utility.

Comment: Apple says otherwise, though I suspect you are correct:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15139/mac

I wouldn't know because I get errors when I try to format my drive as MacOS Journalled. Time Machine has been broken for me since 12.0, just upgraded to 12.5 and it's still broken.

Comment: Yeah, you can force it if it's already a 'registered' TM drive, but it really doesn't want you to if you're formatting afresh. I guess my wording could be less forceful - but I've seen issues with the 'wrong' format when needed for recovery.